# Не работает fstream C++

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, fstream

Изучаю работу с файлами в С++
Сделал абсолютно все как в примере. В консоль выводится сообщение Good!, но при этом файл не создается, а если вручную создать файл , то ничего туда не записывается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        string path = "piin.txt";
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(path);

        if (!fout.is_open())
        {
            cout << " Bad!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " Good!";
            fout << "Мои данные";
        }
        fout.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы ищете созданный файл не в том каталоге :)
Я уж не помню точно, какой там среда VS каталог делает текущим при выполнении - так что или поищите хорошенько в подкаталогах проекта, или укажите точное полное имя файла - типа `"D:\\Programs\\Project\\pii.txt"` (не забудьте про двойные обратные косые черты).

Answer (score 0):

Работаю в  Visual Studio, файл создавался и редактировался в коренной папке проекта! В случае подобной ситуации проверяйте там